# Restore whatsapp chat if no SD-card

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.1-jelly-bean, restore, whatsapp-messenger

I have Samsung Galaxy S3 which I formatted it then when I re-installed WhatsApp, it did not ask me to restore back my chat.
I don't have an SD-card installed in my phone.
What can I do to get back my chat?
Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot recover them because you erased them when formatting, and Whatsapp can't recover them for you from their servers because they are deleted as soon as they are received by the client (you):

http://www.quora.com/How-long-does-WhatsApp-keep-the-delivered-data-like-images-or-etc-in-the-server
https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20887921